# DDR2 modules with same specs but pins don't match?

Tags: memory

I know this is bordering outside the topic of this site, but this is driving me mad... and it's memory for a server anyway, so allow me to cheat a bit, hehe.

Can anyone spot the difference between [this DDR module](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/PartsInfo.asp?root=&LinkBack=&ktcpartno=KVR667D2E5K2/4G) and [this one](http://www.lamicrogroup.com/view_product.asp?product_id=3081)?

Other than the heat spreader, both seem to have the same specs: DDR2 5300 ECC 240pin, but oddly, the pins and the locator slot don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kingston is Unbuffered and the Hynix is Fully Buffered

Comment: Dear lord it seems I'm blind today... Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Not a problem. Maybe it's time for another coffee? :D